# How to rename a foreignkey field with South?

Tags: django, django-south

Renaming a simple charfield etc seems easy ([Django - How to rename a model field using South?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235995/django-how-to-rename-a-model-field-using-south))

However when I try using the same on a ForeignKey field I get an error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP '[new_fkey_field_name]'; check that column/key exists")
```

Which stems from the migration trying to run the *backwards* for some reason (as evidenced in the trace).

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like problem is on MySql side. 
 - What storage engine did you use? 
 - Do you use MyISAM(which does not support referential integrity)? 
 - Did you try the it with sqlite of postgresql?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600129/using-south-to-refactor-a-django-model-with-inheritence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: with `mysql-5.5.30-1.fc18.x86_64` and

```
MySQL-python==1.2.4
Django==1.4.2
South==0.7.6
```

the following works:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration_:
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_column('app_model', 'old_id', 'new_id')
        db.alter_column('app_model', 'new_id',
                        self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(
                            blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            to=orm['app.OtherModel']
                        ))

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_column('app_model', 'new_id', 'old_id')
        db.alter_column('app_model', 'old_id',
                        self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(
                            blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            to=orm['app.OtherModel']
                        ))
```

As @Eloff comments, South can't find the original FK for reasons unknown, but it doesn't seem to matter. There is no need for a data migration (I believe) as pk values should not change.

The field specification (using `self.gf`) is taken from South's auto-generated migrations for consistency.

Comment: You might get bitten by [this little South bug](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1186) if you use this solution. Either monkey-patch South (see ticket) or bribe [Andrew](http://aeracode.org) to fix it

Answer (score 24):

First, you need to use the db column name not the one in the model. Eg: foobar_id not foobar.

Then you need to drop the fk constraints and recreate them after renaming:

```
db.drop_foreign_key('app_model', 'old_id')
db.rename_column('app_model', 'old_id', 'new_id')
db.alter_column('app_model', 'new_id', models.ForeignKey(to=orm['app.OtherModel']))
```

If your fk is nullable you need to use change it to:

```
db.alter_column('app_model', 'new_id', models.ForeignKey(null=True, to=orm['app.OtherModel']))
```

Comment: This doesn't work with MySQL 5.5.13 (south 0.7.3) drop_foreign_key does not find the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Shouldn't alter_column() be using 'new_id'?

Comment: That's really difficult to debug if the fk is nullable. Thanks man

Comment: I think this should really be the accepted answer.  Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 11):

MySQL users ought to be aware of this bug in south, if indeed it still applies:

http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/697

The workaround is to conduct the migration in 3 steps:

1) Add new field

2) data migrate the data to the new field

3) delete the old field

Comment: IMHO, this is the only solution that works reliably with MySQL DBs

Answer (score 6):

When renaming a `ForeignKey`, remember to add `_id` to the end of the field name you use in Django. E.g.

```
db.rename_column('accounts_transaction', 'operator_id', 'responsible_id')
```

And not

```
db.rename_column('accounts_transaction', 'operator', 'responsible')
```

But I have only tested this on sqlite (which don't actually have the ALTER_TABLE at all), so I don't know if it will actually work on mysql/postgres.