# Django Data Migration, using South with Inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration, django-south

We are migrating the data in several instances of our Django project to a new schema.

The old schema had:

```
class Group(models.Model)
class User(models.Model)
```

And the new schema has:

```
class AccessEntity(models.Model)
class Group(AccessEntity)
class User(AccessEntity)
```

We are trying to use South to do a data migration for these groups and users. http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html

I've gathered that I'll need to use forward rules to specify how to migrate the Users but there are a few issues I've run up against.

The main issue is how to keep the ID of the User/Group the same if I were to create a new User object that extends the AccessEntity class.

Users & Groups are referenced to by objects they own or are assigned to them. If I change their ID that information would be lost. Is there a way of keeping the same ID for an object even though I need it to now extend from AccessEntity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the way multi-table model inheritance works ist that there will be an implicit one-to-one field in the parent and child models. So both User and Group would use an ID field of AccessEntity if AccessEntity has such a field.

If you create AccessEntity such that it has a field `ID` you can assign to it when you write a forward (data)-migration. That way you can make sure that the AccessEntity gets the right ID.

If have written a longer [multi-table inheritance tutorial](http://www.paulkoerbitz.de/post/27/refactoring-django-models-with-table-inheritance-using-django-south/) and it looks like you are trying to do something similar.

And furthermore the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600129/using-south-to-refactor-a-django-model-with-inheritence) could also be helpful (note that some things in the original answer does will not work in new versions of django / south, see my tutorial / the answer at the bottom for changes).

What might be a problem in your case is that if you already have data in both User and Groups and the id field is auto-generated, `IDs` likely not be distinct, e.g. you are likely going to have both a User and a Group with `ID==1`. This could be a problem if you want to query based on those `IDs` and of course `ID` could not be a primary key for `AccessEntity` then.